# Loading images to ListField in blackberry

Tags: image, blackberry, guid, listfield

I am loading some data from web service with image.But problem with image loading.

I have to display default image first,then the loaded image is placed on default image asynchronously.I do not have an idea how can i do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use some default image from project resources, same for all rows.

Then for each row run a thread to load image, use a callback in thread to update list field row when image is loaded. See [Coderholic: Blackberry WebBitmapField](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-webbitmapfield/)

Remember that we can use only limited number of threads in Blackberry application. So better create some [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) with 3-5 threads running.

Comment: thanks for the answer Max Gontar, that helped me a lot, one more suggestion needed if I am working on a large list say some hundred,is it a good idea to create 5 thread and allocate 20 images to each thread..?

Comment: @Newbie I think - yes, you're absolutely right! You can create 5 threads and in each thread you can manage a shared vector resource (dont forget to use 'synchronized') with all 100 images, and take out images one by one while processing - that would be smooth enought.

Comment: thanks for your reply Max Gontar, the requirement of my application is little humongous, I have like 300-400 rows in few sections came across a suggestion to load images that are currently visible to users may be + and - few rows at a time..do you have any clue about how to implement it?